# SSRS: how to use a parameter directly in the query?

Tags: ssrs-2012

Here's my query. In the application, the query is a little more complex but the focus is more on how to use the parameter

```
SELECT EmpName, Department, Salary
From tblEmployees
WHERE Salary >= @baseSalary
```

If a user want to select employees whose salaries start from a certain level they can do so.

I've found some videos on Plurasight on how to filter the result, but none on how to use the parameter directly in the query.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create parameters in SSRS and then map them to the query with the Parameter tab in the Dataset Properties. If you use the same name for your parameter as the query, they will map automatically.

Here's an example of how I use them together:

**Parameters**

[image]

**Dataset query**

[image]

**Parameter Tab of Dataset Properties**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my day.